# My Salesforce1 Component is not using full screen area on iPhone

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

I created this Lightning component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" controller="MyComp">
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <div class="dashboard is-dashboard">
      <div class="slds-container--fluid">
         <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--align-center">
            <div class="slds-col">
               <div class="slds-section slds-section--apps channel-direct slds-is-mobile">
                  <div class="slds-section__header">
                     <h3>Applications</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-section__content slds-clearfix">
                     <ul>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.myList}" var="myObj">
                           <li class="slds-list__item slds-text-align--center">
                              <a href="{!myObj.url}" title="{!myObj.title}" target="_BLANK">
                              </a>
                           </li>
                        </aura:iteration>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
</aura:component>
```

And when I preview this

I see my component is only using a very small portion of the available area. How do I make sure it uses the full area?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
<div class="slds-col">
```

to

```
<div class="slds-col" style="width:100%;>
```

That should make sure your component uses all the width available on device.